# Suggestions for Kosher iPhone apps

Tags: technology, phone

I'm an iPhone app developer with mostly Jewish & Israeli iPhone apps and I'm open to new suggestions or ideas for new apps that can be useful for Jewish people.

Anyone here had a case that he needed an iPhone app related to Judaism and couldn't find it in the app store?

Answers should come with explanations of why or how the proposed app would be useful and different from what's already on the market.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this question is a good fit for this site. See [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). Sounds somewhat open-ended and like a discussion. But let's see what others have to say....

Comment: @yydl, [now a meta question](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/491)

Comment: is there a really good, searchable, seforim app for free or a dollar that has all the basic texts (tanach,shas,rambam,etc.)?

Comment: There are many iPhone apps - check out at least here http://www.jewishiphonecommunity.org/category/iphoneipad/tanach and http://www.jewishiphonecommunity.org/category/iphoneipad/talmud-mishnah - not plenty free and under dollar but you can try.

Comment: @ArielK: Bar Ilan Responsa is online.  I'm not sure if it'll work in the iPhone browser, but if it does, you're set.  http://responsa.co.il  (Requires a password.)
You could also do a Google search of Machon Mamre for Tanach (by using the *site:* syntax).

Comment: Any chance you want to become an Android developer instead? Its now the most popular mobile OS in the world. Makes your target demographic that much larger.

Comment: There are also many iphone sefarim available here http://www.jewishcontent.org/iphone/

Comment: Update: someone showed me the best free Torah app: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id449507485?mt=8
It has everything, and the commentaries are linked to the text.

Comment: since its basically all PDFs its a bit difficult to use on an iphone and ipod touch.

Answer (score 3):

I vote for creating an app for this site!

Comment: http://stackapps.com/tags/iphone+app

Comment: @msh210 Oh, man, how did I not know about this? I actually have an Android, which it seems also has several SE apps. How do I choose one???? :)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the SE API does not yet support authentication and won't for some time. In english, that means that you can't write an app for SE that allows you to log in.

Comment: SethJ can you update this answer with how the proposed app would be useful and different from what's already on the market (such as logging in, unless that has been dealt with already)?

Comment: @DoubleAA, did you just downvote me? This is an old answer on a question that sought ideas for things to develop. If an app has since been developed that serves this need, great! I don't think that makes the answer irrelevant, though. That makes me part of history! And, no, I can't think of anything other than logging in, posting, editing, commenting, etc. If there are apps for SE now, great. The Mobile version is pretty flawless on my Droid now, so I have no real complaints other than easier sharing.

Comment: @SethJ I did not downvote. I am commenting in response to a NAA flag. Possibly the flagger downvoted you; I do not know and could not tell you anyway. (It seems though that msh210's comment was posted at the same time as the answer, so the apps had already been developed it seems.)

Comment: @doubleaa, I just checked the Google Play store (formerly the Android market), and it seems that the Stack Exchange API is read-only. I hope this changes soon.

Comment: I think they just did!!

Answer (score 2):

I'd reach out to the OU and Artscroll about creating an app for the OU's website and Artscroll's Hebrew-English Siddur. The OU website works fairly well on some mobile platforms (BB being the most notable exception), but an app would be great, especially for their holiday/Zmanim calendar. They also have tons of other content that would be great to access in an app. And, although there are Siddurim available (I use AndDaaven - I have an Android, not an iPhone), an app for the standard Artscroll Siddur would be most welcome, at least from my perspective.

Answer (score 1):

An app to track counting sefirah would be nice

Comment: Here's one: http://itunes.com/apps/sefira

Comment: There also exists a couple for the Android OS.

Answer (score 1):

Since most Iphone Users have no problem spending random amounts of money for dubiously useful things, I suggest a Random tzedakah app, that send the 70% of profits you are allowed to a random Yeshiva each day you use the app  :)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Or maybe have it be one's local yeshivah?

Answer (score 1):

How about an app called "where am i holding ?" The use case is for people who have long breaks between various chavrusos and they want an easy way to enter where they finished so the next time they open the sefer they can easily remember what daf/halacha they were on ? currently I learn several things during my commute via cdrom and over the weekend I listen to other shiurem so come monday morning i don't always remember where i was holding. Also consider someone who has a once a week chavrusa that spends the first few minutes trying to find their place.

While you could just use your memo app for this, having a dedicated app that had scrolling dials to set the various items would make input a lot faster,easier and usable. No typing needed. The dials could be preset or configurable. My 2 cents

Answer (score 1):

Hashavas avaida app!! With pictures and geo tagging.

Comment: http://www.hashovasavaida.com

Answer (score 0):

some practical apps are required

e.g.

teshuva app
cheshbon haNefesh

Apps that allow for someone'e personal development. They can input a chesbon hanefesh (accounting) of what they did that day. Places they slipped up, things they wont to work on. A to do list of mitzvos. etc.. –

maybe a ask the Rabbi app

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "teshuva app cheshbon haNefesh"?

Comment: Apps that allow for someone'e personal development. They can input a chesbon hanefesh (accounting) of what they did that day. Places they slipped up, things they wont to work on. A to do list of mitzvos. etc..

Answer (score 0):

An app for when someone tries to interrupt you while you are davening. Push a button and it says

> "I am deep in communication with ELOHIM, Creator of the universe and
>   cannot speak with you right now. Please try again in a few minutes"

Answer (score 0):

I manage this new feature of dafyomireview.com

it's a highly advanced new database driven learning/chazara tracking version of the old site but it would be alot more useful as an app.

http://dafyomireview.com/db/

can you help out?